# Make periodic server requests with NSURLSessionDataTask and dispatch_source timer

Tags: ios, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsession

Need some help and explanation, because i'm really stuck in my question.  i need to make this:
1) I make one  request to the server, get some response and then i want to make another request every 7 seconds(example). also get some response. if it satisfy several conditions -> stop timer and do some stuff.

Main problem is that timer never stops, despite the fact that all in all i get response right. i assume that i use GCD incorrectly. because in debug this code behaves really strange.

What i have done:

This is my request function(it became like this after i read about 50 links how to do similar things)

```
-(void)makeRequestWithURL:(NSString*)urlString andParams:(NSString*)params andCompletionHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary *responseData, NSError *error))completionHnadler{

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if (completionHnadler) {
        if (error) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                completionHnadler(nil, error);
            });
        } else {
            NSError *parseError;
            json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                   options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                     error:&parseError];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                completionHnadler(json, parseError);
            });
        }
    }

}];

[postDataTask resume]; }
```

I create my timer like this:

```
dispatch_source_t CreateDispatchTimer(uint64_t interval,
                                  uint64_t leeway,
                                  dispatch_queue_t queue ,
                                  dispatch_block_t block) {
dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
if (timer) {

    // Use dispatch_time instead of dispatch_walltime if the interval is small
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), interval, leeway);
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, block);
    dispatch_resume(timer);
}
return timer; }
```

and called it like this:

```
-(void)checkForPassenger {

timerSource = CreateDispatchTimer(7ull * NSEC_PER_SEC, 1ull * NSEC_PER_SEC, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    if([self getNotificationsRequest] == YES) {
        dispatch_source_cancel(timerSource);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"go on timer");
    }
    NSLog(@"Driver checked for passenger!");

}); }
```

this is the code of periodic response:

```
-(BOOL)getNotificationsRequest {

NSString *urlString = @"http://primetime.by/temproad/do";
NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"event={\"type\": \"in.getNotifications\"}&session_id=%@",session_id];


[self makeRequestWithURL:urlString andParams:params andCompletionHandler:^(NSDictionary *responseData, NSError *error) {
    if ([[responseData objectForKey:@"rc"] intValue] == 0) {


        NSArray *temp_notifications = [responseData objectForKey:@"notifications"];
        if (temp_notifications.count != 0) {
            notification = [[Notification alloc] initWithNotification:[[responseData objectForKey:@"notifications"] objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
    }
}];

if (notification) {
    return YES;
} else {
    return NO;
} }
```

and this is what i do in main request:

```
[self makeRequestWithURL:urlString andParams:params andCompletionHandler:^(NSDictionary *responseData, NSError *error) {

    if ([[responseData objectForKey:@"rc"] intValue] == 0) {
        route = [[Route alloc] initWithData:responseData];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [self checkForPassenger];
        });

    }
}];
NSLog(@"bye");
```

maybe explanation is bad so i can answer any question.
thx

Comment: This timer never stops because you never call `dispatch_suspend`. Rather than having a periodic timer, perhaps you should change your model to dispatch your next request after you get your response. You can use `dispatch_after` for this and then you won't need to use a `dispatch_source`. You also will not have to worry about turning off the timer. This method is also better in that you won't have multiple requests inflight. For example, say the network is slow and you request hasn't returned yet. With a 7 sec timer you'll be re-requesting the data.

Comment: @MobileBen I thought about dispatch_after and also thought about case with multiple requests. But i don't understand another thing what is happening now in code: when firstly data download OK, my completionHandler in `getNotificationsRequest` works fine, so in my opinion when i returned to checkForPassenger, make `dispatch_suspend`, `dispatch_source_cancel` and it's done, but function `makeRequest` is calling about another 3-4 times and return nil data, because server once answered.

Comment: @MobileBen and few words about the my task: another words, after request_1 i need to check every n seconds the server updates by request_2. if request_2 response fits me, i need to stop request_2.

Comment: Okay, I didn't see the `dispatch_source_cancel`, so you are indeed stopping it at some point. So I think the problem is in your getNotificationRequest. One thing I did not see is where is notification declared? So the problem with how you are using getNotificationRequest is that it is calling an async operation, but yet it will return a value immediately. I'm guessing on some of this because I don't have your code.

Comment: As far as going request_1 and request_2, you can chain them. This is why doing the approach I mentioned versus using a timer is more powerful. This means that on success of request_1, you can then invoke request_2. And you are not tied to a specific interval. If you used the timer, it means your block will also need to know if request_1 is done. If you chain them, only request_1 needs to know that on success, try request_2.